# Calculating a 2D pixel array using CUDA, declaring proper Grid and Block sizes

Tags: c++, c, arrays, opengl, cuda

I'm using CUDA to calculate the values of an array of 64x64x4 which has been flattened out. The array contains GLubytes and then in the z column are stored the RGBA values for any given pixel. I've created a kernel to use with CUDA but I figure the dimensions of my blocks and grids are off. The end result is instead of drawing circles, I'm only drawing fourths of circles. The kernel and function that calls is follow:

For clarification: DIAMETER = 64, RADIUS = 32.

```
__global__ void drawKernel(GLubyte *ball)
{
    int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;


    ball[4 * (x * DIAMETER + y)+3] = (GLubyte) 0x0;  
    if ((x * x) + (y * y) <= (RADIUS * RADIUS)){ 
        ball[4 * ((x+32) * DIAMETER + (y+32))+0] = (GLubyte) 0xffffff;  
        ball[4 * ((x+32) * DIAMETER + (y+32))+1] = (GLubyte) 0x0; 
        ball[4 * ((x+32) * DIAMETER + (y+32))+2] = (GLubyte) 0x0; 
        ball[4 * ((x+32) * DIAMETER + (y+32))+3] = (GLubyte) 0xaaaaaa;
    }
}

cudaError_t drawWithCuda()
{
    size_t memorySize = DIAMETER * DIAMETER * 4 *sizeof(GLubyte);
    GLubyte *dev_ball = 0; //device ball
    cudaError_t cudaStatus; //CUDA error status
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(8, 8);
    dim3 numBlocks(DIAMETER/threadsPerBlock.x, DIAMETER/threadsPerBlock.y);

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice(0) failed! CUDA-capable GPU not on board.");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Allocate GPU buffers for GLubyte array 
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_ball, memorySize);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    //Begin CUDA-kernal call

    drawKernel<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(dev_ball);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //Copy from Device
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(ball, dev_ball, memorySize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Device to Host failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    Error:
        cudaFree(dev_ball);

    return cudaStatus;
}
```

My question is: is my problem found in the dimensions of my Block and Grid? Or is it something else?

The output (once I run the arrray ball through openGL) is the following image:
[image]

I should add that when I don't use cuda and just calculate the array values with regular for loops, the logic used inside the kernel works perfectly well and draws circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating this much memory (in `ball`):

```
    size_t memorySize = DIAMETER * DIAMETER * 4 *sizeof(GLubyte);
```

i.e. an array that is 64 x 64 x 4bytes deep

Now let's look at your array index calculations in the kernel:

```
    ball[4 * ((x+32) * DIAMETER + (y+32))+0] = (GLubyte) 0xffffff;
```

Your `x` and `y` are computed as follows:

```
int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;
```

Given your kernel launch dimensions, you are launching a DIAMETER x DIAMETER array of threads, i.e. 64x64.  So each `x` varies from 0 to 63 and each `y` varies from 0 to 63, depending on the thread.

When we plug some of these `x` and `y` values into your kernel, the index computations blow up (exceed the memory allocated):

```
    ball[4 * ((63+32) * 64 + (63+32))+0] = (GLubyte) 0xffffff;
```

This exceeds the 64x64x4 available area in `ball`.  If you ran this code with `cuda-memcheck`, I'm pretty sure you would see out-of-bounds indexing errors.

It seems like maybe your array indexing should be something like:

```
    ball[4 * ((x) * DIAMETER + (y))+0] = (GLubyte) 0xffffff;
```